# Function.prototype.bind for requestAnimationFrame results in unreadable property

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Working on teaching myself canvas for a game I'm trying to make.

So I had everything working and decided to give my game its own object (I already have player objects, etc...). I have a bunch of commented out stuff I'll fix later. But I can't get RAF to work now. The first error I got with `requestAnimationFrame(this.animate)` I Googled and fixed. But this Function.prototyping.bind isn't working for me as I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined (anonymous function)` as an error.

Javascript is fairly new to me (I've kinda decided I've stayed away for good reasons ha). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Game.prototype.animate = function(){
     var that = this;
     setTimeout(function() {

     globalAnimationCancel = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));

//     this.animateObstacles();
//    this.animatePlayer();

//     animatePlayer();
         this.isCollision();
//         this.isLevelUp();
//         this.th

//     isCollision();
//     isLevelUp();
//     thePointCounter.update();
     }, 1000 / fps);
 }
```

Comment: Why are you mixing `setTimeout` with `requestAnimationFrame`??? And it's exactly the same error, with the very same solution.

Comment: What is that `var that = this;` doing there, did you intend to use it somewhere (and why)? Hint: `raf(that.animate.bind(that))`

Comment: @Bergi looks like OP wants to use `requestAnimationFrame` for the render and `setTimeout` to enforce some kind of maximum frame rate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider where the invocation is happening; `setTimeout` is invoking an *anonymous function* within which you reference `this`. However, inside the *anonymous function*, `this` will be `window` (or *undefined*), and hence there is no `this.animate` so there can't be a property *bind*.

Either define these as variables outside the `setTimeout` so you can access them with it without using `this`, or set `var foo = this` and access everything as e.g. `foo.animate`. You seem to already be doing this with your `that` variable but not using it.

---

You can further optimise by moving as much out of the function loop as possible

```
Game.prototype.animate = function(){
    var bound_render;
    function render() {
        console.log(this); // for demo
        // your code to animate goes here
    }
    bound_render = render.bind(this);
    function anim_loop() {
        requestAnimationFrame(bound_render);
        if (true) // some end condition instead of globalAnimationCancel
            globalAnimationCancel = setTimeout(anim_loop, 1000 / fps);
    }
    globalAnimationCancel = setTimeout(anim_loop, 1000 / fps);
}
```

You could create `bound_render` from a *function expression* instead, but I felt separating the `bind` step would improve readability. Similarly with `anim_loop` which could have been done as a *named function expression* passed directly into the *setTimeout*